# heroku : git push heroku master

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I wrote a web app and I want to deploy it by heroku.I'm new to this
and couldn't figure out this problem.I already searched everything
about this but didn't work.Hope you guys can give me some suggestions.

This is my requirements.txt

```
    alabaster==0.7.10
    asn1crypto==0.22.0
    astroid==1.4.9
    astropy==1.3.2
    Babel==2.4.0
    backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0
    comtypes==1.1.2
    conda==4.3.21
    contextlib2==0.5.5
    cryptography==1.8.1
    cycler==0.10.0
    Cython==0.25.2
    cytoolz==0.8.2
    dask==0.14.3
    datashape==0.5.4
    decorator==4.0.11
    distributed==1.16.3
    dj-database-url==0.4.2
    dj-static==0.0.6
    docutils==0.13.1
    entrypoints==0.2.2
    et-xmlfile==1.0.1
    fastcache==1.0.2
    Flask==0.12.2
    Flask-Cors==3.0.2
    gevent==1.2.1
    greenlet==0.4.12
    gunicorn==19.7.1
    h5py==2.7.0
   .......
    xlwings==0.10.4
    xlwt==1.2.0
    zict==0.1.2
    psycopg2==2.6.1
```

When I got error I'll delete the line in requirements.txt.At the first
 I thought that is only one but the truth is more the one not found.Everytime I will commit ater I change requirement.txt.I
 don't know why and how to debug.I hope it can run and I can deploy it.

This is my error

```
C:\Users\user\django_project>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 13090, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9553/9553), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13090/13090), 118.21 MiB | 316.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 13090 (delta 2753), reused 12586 (delta 2529)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.3
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Noticed cffi. Bootstrapping libffi.
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting alabaster==0.7.10 (from -r /tmp/build_62ec9f69c217d0564bde759554f34c5d/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading alabaster-0.7.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
.......
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement comtypes==1.1.2 (from -r /tmp/build_62ec9f69c217d0564bde759554f34c5d/requirements.txt (line 19)) (from versions: 0.6.4, 1
.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.3.post2)
remote:        No matching distribution found for comtypes==1.1.2 (from -r /tmp/build_62ec9f69c217d0564bde759554f34c5d/requirements.txt (line 19))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

Comment: Are you required to use version 1.1.2 for `comtypes`, or can you upgrade it to 1.1.3?

Comment: I think my approach here would be to do `pip install <package name> -U` for each package that can't be found, re-run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and then try to deploy on Heroku.

Comment: After a second look, are you sure all of those dependencies are for your project? You're requiring packages for both Django and Flask, which makes me think you might have done `pip freeze` on system packages instead of a virtualenv.

Comment: I just followed this document [link](https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/heroku/)

Comment: And I did `install -r requirement.txt` but it showed every packages is satisfied except psycopg2==2.6.1.I changed the version of it in 2.7.3 but showed permission error.I tried to delete it but the package is satisfied still couldn't find it.